# How to use C++ with gsoap to read email from outlook using exchange web services

Tags: c++, authentication, office365, exchangewebservices, gsoap

how can we use C++ with gSOAP to fetch email data from outlook mail (in office 365) using exchange web services. Is there need to be authentication API of office 365, and if yes, then does this API support C++ language.

OR gSOAP is enough to read the data of email from exchange server of office 365. and in gSOAP is there need to be authentication, If yes then which one? please help me.

Comment: Please give me any idea for getting started..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use Office 365 REST APIs for Mail, Calendar and Contacts. Check out http://dev.outlook.com for more info.

Comment: So does this https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations API will support C++? Since there are code written in C# and javascript.

Comment: Yes, since it is a REST API, you should be fine using C# and javascript.  All you need is to be able to construct Http requests, and process responses with JSON body.

Comment: Hey Venkat, I want to make a custom service which not only work with office365 but also all other available Exchange server, So what do think to prefer me for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Exchange Web Services, you can authenticate with Basic auth.

Comment: Okey!! But what about gSOAP should i use this or just API is enough to fetch data with authentication. and if i use gSOAP library, then is there need to be authentication?

Comment: Never used gSOAP, so I can't really give a recommendation either way on that. You always have to authenticate, so however gSOAP implements Basic would probably work.

Comment: hey jason, one more thing is that can i use microsoft's C++ REST SDK to use the office 365 API (Outlook mail API) for fetch data from exchange server ?